# How to use WikiMapia as GeoServer?

Tags: geography, data-acquisition, geodesy

I wish to use the Wikimapia map as background in `GeoGraphics`. According to the [Wikimapia Docs](http://wikimapia.org/docs/Main_Page), [Wikimapia's URL is encoded as follows](http://wikimapia.org/docs/User_interface#Wikimapia.27s_URL):

> An example Wikimapia URL is
>   http://wikimapia.org/#lat=53.9560855&lon=-1.9335937&z=3&l=0&m=a&v=2.
>   The purpose of each of the variables is:
>
> - lat=    The latitude of the centre cross in decimal degrees
> - lon=    The longitude of the centre cross in decimal degrees
> - z=  The zoom level. The closest available tends to be the range z=14 to z=18 but there are exceptions such as the oceans or major cities.

From the above I conclude that the `StringTemplate` for `GeoServer` should be encoded as `` "http://wikimapia.org/#lat=`2`&lon=`3`&z=`1`" `` but it does not work:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[], GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], 
 GeoServer -> {"http://wikimapia.org/#lat=`2`&lon=`3`&z=`1`"}]
```

returns the `GeoGraphics::data` error.

What is the correct way to use Wikimapia as the source of map for `GeoGraphics`?

Comment: The link you provided is not to a "tile server" (it appears Wikimapia does not offer one). Such servers return images of map tiles corresponding to the parameters in a request, rather than a user interface like the link you gave. Here are some alternatives: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers (url in narrow column toward right)

Comment: If I may, I found easier to download the tiles I needed and the rasterize them using the coordinates of the bounding box (with the right coordinates). Of course, you wouldn't be using GeoGraphics then. (Just additional information, not really an answer)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the comments [mfvonh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5059/mfvonh) correctly points out that the Wikimapia's URL in my question is a user interface URL, not a tile server URL. The tile server link template is documented in a message which appears when one sends incorrect request to the tile server:

[image: message]

From the above it is clear that the `StringTemplate` should be as follows:

```
StringTemplate["http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&zoom=`1`"]
```

The tile server also accepts `lng` parameter which specifies the language of the map (addition of `&lng=0` selects English) and `type` parameter which specifies the type of the map: `hybrid` (semi-transparent) or `map` (the default for the tile server, doesn't have alpha-channel). The largest supported zoom level is 22, so we should add the `"ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}` option. Wikimapia as well as Google and OpenStreetMap uses the

> EPSG:3857 - WGS 84/Pseudo-Mercator (Spherical Mercator)

projection which seems to be the default for `GeoGraphics`, so we may not specify it explicitly.

Testing:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&zoom=`1`&lng=0"], 
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}]
```

[image: geographics]

Let us try to use the Wikimapia API for highlighting the basement of the Eiffel Tower:

```
data = Import[
   "http://api.wikimapia.org/?key=example&function=place.getbyid&id=55&format=json&pack=&\
language=en", "JSON"];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{DotDashed, Blue, Thick}], FaceForm[], 
  Polygon[("polygon" /. data)[[;; , ;; , 2]]]}, 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&zoom=`1`&lng=0"], 
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}, GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: geographics3]

Compare with the default map:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{DotDashed, Blue, Thick}], FaceForm[], 
  Polygon[("polygon" /. data)[[;; , ;; , 2]]]}, GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: geographics4]

Obtain satellite image of the Eiffel Tower from Google and highlight its basement (in this template the version number of Google maps `v=196` may require updating to the current version number):

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.005]}], FaceForm[], 
  Polygon[("polygon" /. data)[[;; , ;; , 2]]]}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://khms<*Mod[#2+#3,4]*>.googleapis.com/kh?x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`&v=196"], 
   "ZoomRange" -> {1, 21}}]
```

[image: geographics5]

Obtain satellite image from Google and overlay it with the semi-transparent map from Wikimapia:

```
satellite = 
  GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{48.8635510693252, 2.24669540329895}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://khms<*Mod[#2+#3,4]*>.googleapis.com/kh?x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`&v=196"],  
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 21}}, 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Kilometers"], AspectRatio -> 1];
overlay = GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{48.8635510693252, 2.24669540329895}], 
   GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
      "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&zoom=`1`&lng=0&type=hybrid"], 
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}, GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]];
GraphicsRow[{satellite, overlay}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: graphics row]

```
ImageCompose @@ Cases[{satellite, overlay}, _Image, -1]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome stuff. I never used wikimapia. What are its main benefits?

Comment: @Emy Wikimapia is clearly superior to OpenStreetMap and Google when you need detailed map for little-inhabited or uninhabited areas. But the main (and AFAIK unique) feature of Wikimapia is a Wiki article for *every* object on the map.

Comment: Nice. I looked at this yesterday and could get their api to work quite well, but couldn't find the tile hook. (+1).

Comment: Unfortunately the access to googleapi does not work anymore:
 
 GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{48.8635510693252, 2.24669540329895}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://khms<*Mod[#2+#3,4]*>.googleapis.com/kh?x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`&v=196"],  
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 21}}, 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Kilometers"], AspectRatio -> 1]

gives an error. What has to be changed to enable this again?

Comment: @hippo3773 Seemingly you should update the version number of Google maps `v=196` to current version number. But I do not know the current number, you can find it by monitoring URLs which GoogleEarth requests.

Comment: Yes - thanks! I found another syntax which works perfectly and which does not require the version number of Google maps:

    `GeoServer -> "http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`"`