# How can I delineate the outline of a complex shape?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I have a picture of a lake as follows:

[image: lake]

And I want to delineate the outline of the lake. I binarized the picture and obtained `img`:

[image: bin]

```
tmp = img // ImageCrop[#, {900, 1200}, Bottom] & // DeleteBorderComponents // ComponentMeasurements[#, "ConvexVertices"] &
data = Range[913] /. tmp
```

With the coordinate `data` I can:

```
Flatten[#, 1] &[data] // Graphics[Point[#]] &
```

And it looks like this:

[image: fin]

However, I don't know how to join them up to a closed shape, and there are too many points outside my assumed ``outline". Is there any way to solve my problem? Thank you!

**Edit**: To make it clearer, I draw this schematic diagram.

[image: schematic]

Comment: `MinFilter[GradientFilter[image, 1], 8] // ImageAdjust`

Comment: Please draw a thick red line onto another image showing what do you understand by the "border"

Comment: Since you obtain the map as satellite image from Google you can use Wikimapia API for obtaining the perimeter of the lake. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89953/280) I demonstrate how to do this on the example of highlighting the basement of the Eiffel Tower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another method which utilizes the third argument of `ComponentMeasurements`.

At first we mark the key regions on the original image:

```
i = RemoveAlphaChannel@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQTI.png"];
pointsOfInterest = {{516, 400}, {234, 231}, {426, 653}, {178, 489}};
Show[i, Epilog -> {Red, Disk[#, Offset[10]] & /@ pointsOfInterest}]
```

> [image]

Then we select only components whose minimal bounding boxes include these points of interest:

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[
   ColorNegate@
    Closing[EdgeDetect[ColorSeparate[ColorConvert[i, "LAB"]][[1]], 3, .010], 4]];
comps = ComponentMeasurements[m, "MinimalBoundingBox", 
   Or @@ RegionMember[Polygon[{#}]][pointsOfInterest] &];
iC = Colorize[m, ColorRules -> Append[Thread[comps[[;; , 1]] -> White], _ -> Black]];
Show[HighlightImage[i, MorphologicalPerimeter@iC], 
 Graphics[{Text[#1, Total[#2]/4, Background -> Yellow], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[LightYellow],
      Polygon[{#2}]} & @@@ comps], Graphics[{White, Line[{{180, 532}, {197, 541}}]}]]
```

> [image]

Then we find the perimeter of the lake:

```
HighlightImage[i, 
 MorphologicalPerimeter[FillingTransform@ColorNegate@Opening[ColorNegate@iC, 4]]]
```

> [image]

The only problem with this solution is that the bridge is excluded from the perimeter. We can fix this manually:

```
HighlightImage[i, 
 MorphologicalPerimeter[
  FillingTransform@
   ColorNegate@
    Opening[ColorNegate@
      Rasterize[Show[iC, 
        Epilog -> {White, Polygon[{{180, 532}, {195, 467}, {219, 473}, {201, 542}}]}], 
       "Image"], 4]]]
```

> [image]

Now the result is almost perfect.

Answer (score 8):

```
i = RemoveAlphaChannel@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQTI.png"];
m = MorphologicalComponents[
   ColorNegate@Closing[EdgeDetect[ColorSeparate[ColorConvert[i, "LAB"]][[1]], 3], 4]];
Colorize[m]
```

> [image]

Let us find 5 largest components:

```
Reverse[SortBy[ComponentMeasurements[m, "Count"], Last]][[;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {3 -> 298285, 1 -> 34737, 7 -> 24297, 60 -> 7285, 32 -> 3610}
> ```

By trial an error we find that we need components `3` and `7`:

```
iC = Colorize[m, ColorRules -> {3 -> Black, 7 -> Black, _ -> White}]
```

> [image]

```
iF = FillingTransform@ColorNegate@Opening[iC, 4]
```

> [image]

Finding the perimeter of the lake:

```
perimeter = MorphologicalPerimeter[iF]
```

> [image]

Overlay on the original image:

```
ImageAdd[i, perimeter]
```

> [image]

The result isn't perfect but can serve as a good start.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not completely sure that this is what you're looking for, but `Closing` might be the function you're after.  Example:

```
DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[Closing[EdgeDetect[img], 3]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just post a simple scheme:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQTI.png"]
```

Get the edge

[image]

Highlight it and finish this work.

```
HighlightImage[img, line]
```

[image]