# GeoGraphics with GeoServer option to fetch Google Maps in Mathematica 11

Tags: geodesy, geographics

The GeoServer option in Mathematica 11 can be used to get a Google-Maps satellite background in GeoGraphics; a very useful feature. E.g.

```
GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{67.603, 161.976}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&\
zoom=`1`&lng=0"], "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Kilometers"], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

However, this fails if the domain is on (exotic?) coastlines, such as in north-eastern Siberia:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{68.603, 161.976}], 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://i<*Mod[#2,4]+Mod[#3,4]*4*>.wikimapia.org/?x=`2`&y=`3`&\
zoom=`1`&lng=0"], "ZoomRange" -> {1, 22}}, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Kilometers"], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Is there a way to make this call foolproof for any location? Google Maps have respective tiles all over the world, including the ocean?

Comment: Without knowing how these tile servers work, from the error messages it appears that wikimapia is giving back tiles that are not uniformly sized in the non-working example.  You should ask Alexey why [his code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89953/9490) is failing here

Comment: The error message complains about zoom level 10 so limit the zoom range `"ZoomRange" -> {1, 9}}`