# GeoGraphics: road labels

Tags: geographics

I am using Mathematica 11.2.0. My question is: How can I reveal all available state/interstate route labels?

```
GeoGraphics[
  GeoMarker @ GeoPosition@{38.68, -77.32}, GeoRange -> Quantity[20, "Miles"]]
```

returns a map with three state route labels and no interstate highway labels.

When `GeoZoomLevel -> 11` is added, more state route labels appear, as does Interstate 95 (but not the Beltway I-495). Yet these routes appear unlabeled in the earlier map.

How can all available labels be made to appear in the first command without using `GeoZoomLevel`?  Apparently the labels are present in the OpenStreetMap data but need to be coaxed out.

I haven't found this matter treated on this forum but if it is, please point it out.

Comment: Just an alternative approach: you can try to obtain semi-transpared layer with the labels [from Wikimapia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89953/280).